# qbxml quickbooks item customfield filter

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

Is there a way to produce an XML request to get only one item and its information by filtering one of custom fields?

For example, I have a "barcode" custom field and I want to get an item by its barcode number.

Comment: No. You cannot filter by custom fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: No. You cannot filter by custom fields