# qbXML to Filter Items by Custom Fields?

Tags: xml, quickbooks

Is it possible to get a list of Items from QuickBooks and filter it based on Custom Fields? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759630/qbxml-quickbooks-item-customfield-filter) from 2013 but I am not sure if it has changed since then since this seems like a pretty important feature.

Something like this:

```
<!---- LIST ALL ITEMS OF THE CATEGORY "MyCategory" ---->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
  <ItemQueryRq requestID="{REQUEST_ID}" >
      <Category>MyCategory</Category>
    </ItemQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

If not, is it possible to get the custom fields in an Item Request? If so, I could manually sift through and filter all the items in the response, but the response I get only seems to only return Standard Fields.

If it is relevant, I am using the Web Connector and QuickBooks Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuit's documentation is here, and lists what you can filter by:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/itemquery

No, you cannot filter by custom fields.

The documentation about querying and getting back custom fields is here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/develop/tutorials/data-extensions-custom-fields-and-private-data#query-requests-for-dataext-data

You need to do this to get custom fields (`OwnerID`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <ItemQueryRq requestID="{REQUEST_ID}" >
      <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
    </ItemQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```